# zeppelin-solidity: WhyHasNoEther contract prevent accidental loss of Ether

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I am writing smart contract. I am looking for Zeppelin with many helpful methods. But there is one contract that I don't understand named [HasNoEther.](https://openzeppelin.org/api/docs/ownership_HasNoEther.html)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./Ownable.sol";


/**
 * @title Contracts that should not own Ether
 * @author Remco Bloemen <remco@2π.com>
 * @dev This tries to block incoming ether to prevent accidental loss of Ether. Should Ether end up
 * in the contract, it will allow the owner to reclaim this ether.
 * @notice Ether can still be send to this contract by:
 * calling functions labeled `payable`
 * `selfdestruct(contract_address)`
 * mining directly to the contract address
*/
contract HasNoEther is Ownable {

  /**
  * @dev Constructor that rejects incoming Ether
  * @dev The `payable` flag is added so we can access `msg.value` without compiler warning. If we
  * leave out payable, then Solidity will allow inheriting contracts to implement a payable
  * constructor. By doing it this way we prevent a payable constructor from working. Alternatively
  * we could use assembly to access msg.value.
  */
  function HasNoEther() public payable {
    require(msg.value == 0);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Disallows direct send by settings a default function without the `payable` flag.
   */
  function() external {
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfer all Ether held by the contract to the owner.
   */
  function reclaimEther() external onlyOwner {
    assert(owner.send(this.balance));
  }
}
```

In the document:

> This tries to block incoming ether to prevent accidental loss of
>   Ether. Should Ether end up in the contract, it will allow the owner to
>   reclaim this ether.

I don't understand why block incoming ether to prevent accidental loss of Ether. (because I think it is vice versa that we should block outcoming ether). Second question is: Whey this contract write this fallback function, we can prevent all incoming ether.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prevents accidental loss of ETH by forbiding to just send ETH to the contract by mistaking, without calling a specific payable function which will handle the payment.

---

Let's create a simple scenario :

You want to send ETH to your friend Bob. Except instead of pasting in your favorite third-party app wallet(-manager) like MetaMask or MEW, you pasted the address of the contract. You only realize your mistake after sending the ETH. If the contract didn't forbid sending ETH to it without calling a specific function, like `payMe`, your ETH is basically lost.

Comment: thanks so much :D in my contract when inherited to `HasNoEther`, when I add a fallback function (with payable annotation), I meet an error: "TypeError: Overriding function visibility differs" So because I use `HasNoEther` contract, I cannot use fallback function anymore right ? But in case I need this, how I can solve. thanks.

Comment: You will need to get rid of the fallback function in the `HasNoEther` contract.

Comment: Do you think if we do this, we violate design of the library ? I mean, does zeppelin author have another way. thanks.

Comment: Then, don't use the `HasNoEther` contract if you are going to delete its key functionnality. ;)